# JavaFX web engine doesn't fully run javascript

Tags: java, javafx, webview

So I want to create a browser in java and I want it to be able to execute scripts such as Coin-hive to mine cryptocurrencies. My code:

```
public class WebViewSample extends Application {

    private Scene scene;

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(),750,720, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();//stage.setFullScreen(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

}

class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        webEngine.load("http://c0nw0nk.github.io/CoinHive/");//127.0.0.1/mine.html
        getChildren().add(browser);
    }

}
```

Now, for some reason (even when I try to use custom html or different OS) the miner doesn't run at all.

I also tried to use "JBrowserDriver" with custom html that should have perform http GET as an indication of miner running, with no success.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? What other alternatives are out there (programmed with Java and includes GUI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked CoinHive library in WebView. There is a problem with `miner.start()` because `miner.isRunning()` returns false. I unminified [coinhive.min.js](https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js) with [unminify.com](http://unminify.com/) so I was able to execute hidden function `miner._startNow()`. Currently `isRunning` function is returning true but script is still not working. Makes me think that there's lack of support for 3rd party browsers and you have to play with this to make it work. The code that I used to test library:

```
public class CoinHive extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener((webView, message, lineNumber, sourceId) -> {
            System.out.println(message + "[at " + lineNumber + "]");
        });

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println(newValue);
        });

        engine.getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            newValue.printStackTrace();
        });

        StringBuilder codeBuilder = new StringBuilder("<script src='https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js'></script>");
        codeBuilder.append("<script>window.onload = function() { var miner = new CoinHive.Anonymous('6Y2vO0GuPf3nInwjZfxSHdwE8gKUHsLE', {throttle:0.1,threads:1});");
        codeBuilder.append("miner.start(); console.log(miner.isRunning()); };");
        codeBuilder.append("</script>");
        engine.loadContent(codeBuilder.toString());

        Scene scene = new Scene(webView, 600, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("CoinHive WebView");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

You're also asking about an alternative for html/js based ui. You can use [JCEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef) (*The Java Chromium Embedded Framework*) to embed chromium in your application. Unfortunately it works only with AWT/Swing, it's too complicated to embed it in [SwingNode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) and you have to support each platform on your own. If you don't want to build JCEF you can use some maven builds and forks like:

- [GitHub: Pandomium](https://github.com/Panda-Programming-Language/Pandomium) - fork with maven builds and natvies
- [Maven: JavaCef](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bitbucket.johness/java-cef) - clean maven builds

I loaded the specified website (http://c0nw0nk.github.io/CoinHive/) on Pandomium and it works:

[image: CoinHive::Pandomium Screenshot]

The code that I used with Pandomium library:

```
public class CoinHive extends JFrame {

    public CoinHive(PandomiumBrowser browser) {
        super.setSize(1560, 780);
        super.setTitle("CoinHive");
        super.getContentPane().add(browser.toAWTComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        super.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PandomiumSettings settings = PandomiumSettings.getDefaultSettings();

        Pandomium pandomium = new Pandomium(settings);
        pandomium.initialize();

        PandomiumClient client = pandomium.createClient();
        PandomiumBrowser browser = client.loadURL("http://c0nw0nk.github.io/CoinHive/");

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new CoinHive(browser));
    }

}
```